# PouchDB bi-directional sync with Cloudant failure

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to sync a local user data store (PouchDB) back to Cloudant however in chrome I'm receiving three errors:

First Error

request:
    https://username.cloudant.com/?_nonce=Hz8xwDku9d4vvorf
response:
    {"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

Second Error

request:
    https://username.cloudant.com/?_nonce=ml2mu2jJjMUnKpnw
response
    {"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

Third Error

request:
    https://username.cloudant.com/remote_db/_local/48Y4.efvo8bosN3v5QMY3A==?_nonce=SM5SwURV6nLHA5f2
responseL
    {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

Using the latest version of PouchDB version 3.2.1

```
var db = new PouchDB(dbname, {adapter : 'websql'});

        var options = {
            live: true, 
            filter: 'userdb/by_profileId', 
            query_params: { "PROFILEID": dbname}, 
            include_docs: {conflicts: true, attachments: true}
    };

        db.replicate.from(source, options);
        db.replicate.to(source, options);
```

I'm not sure why the first and second refer to database that doesn't exist. I'm able to make changes to the local datastore without any errors I just cant sync to the remote datastore (Cloudant). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what happened but since upgrading to version 3.3.0 of PouchDB the issue no longer appears.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't include your Cloudant username/password? Or maybe Cloudant doesn't allow PouchDB to create a new database on your behalf? Check the Network panel to see if PouchDB attempted to PUT a new database, and what Cloudant said in response.

Comment: Yes, I included the username and password in the url.